# ViewErrorBag Empty - Validation is not passing errors

Tags: laravel

**Controller**

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'prox_scan' => 'required',
        'full_name' => ['required', new ValidateFullName],
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/prox_login')
                    ->withErrors($validator)
                    ->withInput();
    }
```

**View**

```
@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

I have test the Controller and the error messages are being generated properly. But when it redirects to the view, the `ViewErrorBag` is empty. Solutions I've tried:

- Checked `Handler.php` to make sure `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,` is in the `middleware` section, it does
- Updated composer
- Updated Laravel to Laravel 8

Here is the response when `dd($errors)`:

```
Illuminate\Support\ViewErrorBag {#297 ▼
  #bags: []
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Laravel 7+ (at least), the `Kernel.php` file contained middleware and middlewareGroups. For both arrays, the following two classes are included:

- `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,`
- `\Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,`

You just need to remove these two lines from `middlewareGroup` but leave them in `middleware`. My assumption is that having the two lines in both causes the $errors variable to be reset to empty every time.